# Microsoft Excel 97 easter egg

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Does anyone remember the Microsoft Excel 97 easter egg? There were a series of inputs and keyboard presses you have to do in the cells that would take you to a 3-D space world with mountains and you flew around and eventually came to a mountain that listed all the developer names.

Just curious because I was just talking to a buddy of mine about our early computer days in high school when this subject came up.

So my question is, what were the commands for that easter egg and did Microsoft ever incorporate the same easter egg in later versions?  Could you directly access a certain file in the Microsoft folder to view it?  Being a huge fan of (technical) easter eggs (lol), I'm just curious how the mechanics of it worked.

Comment: http://eeggs.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a bunch of them -

> 1. On a new Worksheet, Press F5
> 2. Type X97:L97 and hit enter
> 3. Press the tab key
> 4. Hold Ctrl-Shift
> 5. Click on the Chart Wizard toolbar button
> 6. Use mouse to fly around - Right button forward/ Left button reverse

If you received an error while entering the X97:L97 code in EXCEL to try and reach the simulator, try this one for newer versions of EXCEL.

---

> 1. On a blank worksheet press F5.
> 2. In the "Go To" windows enter "r97c12:r97c24"
> 3. Press enter.
> 4. Press the TAB key.
> 5. Hold down Control + Shift.
> 6. Click the chart wizard tool-bar icon.

---

Both of them don't work in Excel 2007 - which is what I have. [More at Easter Eggs](http://eeggs.com/tree/279.html)